# how to download different type of files in rest web service using java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, file, download

I want to download files which i wrote @POST method in rest web service using java.
I used with FileIOStream, but i find that i can download images and zip file types,but file is corrupted.
Do anyone know which library file i need to use in order to download all kinds of file types.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the @Produces (or @Consumes) annotation to specify what type of data is being sent or received.

@Consumes({"text/plain,text/html,application/zip"})
will allow a service to receive plain text, html and zip.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gipxf/index.html